# What is MySQL internal doing with a where condition that only contains a column name?

Tags: mysql

I accidentally  noticed that it's possible to write selects like:

```
select * from this_table where a
```

in this case "a" is a column of table "this_table".

The result is always empty.

- Why is such a select possible?
- What is MySQL doing ?
- Are there any cases where a select like this makes sense?

Comment: I would assume MySQL will return rows whose `a` evaluates to "true". Such as: `FROM myTable WHERE isFlagged`

Comment: When in doubt you can always use EXPLAIN to see wether a condition is being used and how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'a' will be evaluated in a boolean context. If it is a boolean it's easy to guess what the outcome will be, for other types they are converted to booleans first.

[http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f02e8/3](http://fiddle)